# How do I preserve coloured output when piping to `less -R`?

Tags: pipe, colors, less, pty

```
$ ffmpeg -v debug ...
```

Coloured output.

```
$ ffmpeg -v debug ... |& less -R
```

Dull output.

How do I make the output coloured while piping it to something?

Comment: The problem is not with `less`, but with `ffmpeg`, which seems to disable coloring when stdout is not associated with a terminal. Some utilities like `grep` have a `--color=always` option. You should look at what `ffmpeg` provides.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For commands that do not have an option similar to `--color=always`, you can do, e.g. with your example:

```
script -c "ffmpeg -v debug ..." /dev/null < /dev/null |& less -R
```

What `script` does is that it runs the command in a terminal session.

EDIT: Instead of a command string, if you want to be able to provide an array, then the following zsh wrapper script seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
script -c "${${@:q}}" /dev/null < /dev/null |& less -R
```

Comment: Very useful, didn't know about [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)!

Comment: How do I run `script` with argument array instead of a string?

Comment: @Vi. I suspect that an argument array isn't used for some reason (same things for the zsh zsh/zpty module). If this is really important, you can write a wrapper that will accept an array and generate the right `script` invocation (not easy, but perhaps it has already been done somewhere…).

Comment: @Vi. Is my zsh wrapper script OK for an array in your case?

Comment: @vinc17, I already have such script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069163/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-command-line-arguments-to-from-string . It does not try to quote anything (which I consider insecure), but uses base64 and explicit deserializer.

Comment: @Vi. But this is different: the deserializers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069163/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-command-line-arguments-to-from-string generate an array, which cannot be used with `script`. Here, with `script`, you *need* to quote. Also note that `script -c` and `sh -c` behave differently on the literal newline character, so that the quoting mechanism would be different for `sh -c`.

Comment: @vinc17, Usage of serialize/deserialize is like this: `CODE=$(serialize ffmpeg -v debug -i /dev/null) script -c 'deserialize $CODE' /dev/null`

Comment: @Vi. OK. However this depends on external scripts. I mean that you can't easily embed everything in a single script, which could be regarded as a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to `script`, which expectes command line as a string instead of normal array, there is a special mode of [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr):

```
reptyr -L ffmpeg -v debug ... < /dev/null |& less -R
```

Note that not all versions of `reptyr` have working `-L` option and accept `< /dev/null` gracefully. See my pull request for this.

Comment: Under Debian/unstable, `reptyr -L ...` doesn't work ("Unable to read terminal attributes: Inappropriate ioctl for device"), and with the `-l` option, the color is lost just like with a normal pipe. :(

Comment: @vinc17, Try feeding some other valid terminal instead of `/dev/null` to make it happy. I've submitted a pull request to `reptyr` to make it continue if input is not a terminal.

Comment: Anyone know how to keep `frame=  206 fps= 29 q=-0.0 Lsize=     607kB time=00:00:06.80 bitrate= 731.7kbits/s speed=0.97x` printed. Those line disappear when piped.